# Where can I find EDI Specification Documents

Tags: edi

I am working with several EDIs. Clients has given those EDI spcifications. But sometime I need to other EDI specification documents also. I can search and find them from google which are specifications of different companies. I want the original EDI documentation given by ANSI ASC X12. I have logged in their website http://www.x12.org/ and checked the resources and other areas but not found. 
Can anyone please help me to find these specifications?

Comment: What is it you have 'not found' on the x12 site?  There seems to be plenty of information there (including standards).

Comment: X12 isn't published freely like EDIFACT.  It's actually quite expensive to get to the standards library.  OP should be mapping to the trading partner's guidelines anyway, or use what he finds online and modifies it to suit needs.  It's been done that way for years.

Comment: Matt, thanks for your reply. I need Standard EDI Specification for a particular EDI. For example this is an EDI Spcification, which a company has modified according to their need [EDI 856](https://www.dandh.com/docs/EDI_Guides%5CCustomer%5CImplementation%20Guide%20856,%204010.pdf). But I need standard specification if X12 or any other organization provides.

Comment: @Andrew, Thanks for reply. May be it is not available freely. But lets see if anybody has any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found few EDI Specifications in html format in lots of linked pages. These are very helpful to me. I hope this will be helpful to many more people. Please check this link http://ecomgx17.ecomtoday.com/edi/. 
If anyone have knowledge of better link, please shere. Thanks everybody for reply!

Answer (score 1):

Try [here](https://github.com/EdiFabric/Integration/tree/RemoveX12Files/BizTalk%20Server/Schema/X12), a bunch of X12 schemas were published by Microsoft. You can then navigate to the exact version folder and examine the 856 XSD, the structure of which should match the standard one from X12.

Comment: Thanks @JimA78 for reply. These are good but it should be good if these can be found in pdf or html format. I also want list of possible values.